# Python script is running in IDLE but not in pycharm

Tags: python

Script is running in IDLE but not in Pycharm

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Ie("c:\\Users\\n0317311\\Desktop\\IEDriverServer.exe")
driver.get("http://www.google.co.in")
```

Script is expected to launch a IE browser and navigate to google page. This is happening, when i run the script from IDLE. however, when i run from Pycharm, below error is thrown. May i know why this error is popped up, while running the script from Pycharm only please?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/n0317311/PycharmProjects/Python Programmes/opening browser.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

Comment: This is happening because you are not running the same python executable and one of them is finding the webdriver library and the other is not finding it.
Try to check the python executble that is running correctly, to check it, please execute this:

import sys
print(sys.executable)

You will see they are different executables so just change Pycharm executable to be the correct one in Preferences -> Project Interpreter

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html That should help you